# C# JSON Deserialize OUTPUT NULL

Tags: c#, json, string

```
    //Then

          client.AddCommand("INFODENSUS88", async (x) =>
                {
                    string html = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.erevollution.com/en/api/military-unit/177");
    //output html is working fine
                    using (var sr = new StringReader(html))
                    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {
                        var js = new JsonSerializer();
                        var u = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(jr);
                        Console.WriteLine(u.CommanderName);
                        await x.Message.Parent.SendMessage(u.CommanderName);
                    }
    //output u.commandername = NULL
                });

OUTPUT = NULL
```

When i start the program , dont have any output / NULL
T_T someone help me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Html returns JSON array and you are trying to convert into the single object, make following changes in your code :

```
 var u = js.Deserialize<RootObject[]>(jr);
 Console.WriteLine(u[0].CommanderName);
 await x.Message.Parent.SendMessage(u[0].CommanderName);
```

Here i will only return CommanderName of the first object in array.